# Is it Possible to Convert Existing Java Projects into Spring-Batch Jobs

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

**My question without the fluff**

Is Spring-Batch the right tool for converting a handful of one-off (one and done type) java projects that tend to interact with a database at some point, into their own separate "Jobs" that are part of a Spring-Batch project?

---

**With Fluff/Background**

The company I work for has several "one off" java projects that really only do one thing (either at some arbitrary time, or just whenever we tell it) and then they are done. They tend to interact with the database at some point in their lifecycle, but not necessarily at the same time.

There are a couple more projects/scripts that I'm tasked with creating, but instead of having nearly 10 different perl scripts and a few handful of jars out on our box, we would like to maybe stuff all these projects in one place and just be ran when we need to run them (ideally on a remote box via command line args). From the research I've done on Spring-Batch, it kind of sounds like exactly what we are looking for, especially the functionality [described here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/htmlsingle/#runningJobsFromCommandLine).

I'm moderately familiar with Spring-Boot and the Spring Framework, but for some reason reading up on Jobs and the setup, the domain language seems a little foreign to me, and I just want to make sure I'm not wasting my time trying to figure this out if it's not realistic. We would like this to just be one cozy place for any current or future projects that are ran independently so that we minimize clutter on our box. Just to clarify, I keep saying projects, but from what I understand, these projects need to be converted to Jobs if they are to be part of a Spring-Batch project. Is this realistic?

Comment: It depends on what percentage of those one-off projects is plumbing and what percentage is actual business logic. If you find high percentage of plumbing code then consider Spring Batch or especially if you are dealing with external recouses then consider an EIP solution like Apache Camel or Spring Integration

Comment: plumbing code as in anything non-business logic specific, things like: 1) how do i schedule it, 2) how do i connect to a resource, 3) how do i retry , 4) what if it fails in a particular way and i want to continue, 5) how do i transform to/from a data format (xml/json/csv), 6) how do i monitor, 7) how to get notification etc..

Comment: @dimitrisli Gotchya, I deleted my comment cause I figured a google search would suffice, but thanks for the break down. I'm not sure where to draw the line, and it's statements like that that make me doubt this as a solution. Right now there are just a couple projects that really only go out to a database, grab some stuff, do some stuff to the stuff, and then either put it back or put it elsewhere. But that may necessarily be the norm for future projects. From that, do you think the EIP solutions you mentioned are worth looking into instead? Sorry for the long comment...

Comment: These sound like simple use-cases without a lot of moving parts to them so it might not worth the while the learning curve of an EIP framework. As you go along focus on the reusable components to facilitate your new-project generation. I'm summing a bit of all the above to an answer :)

Comment: Appreciate it. I was trying to make an edit, but realized I typed too bloody much already. I think I know what your saying after re-reading your comment, but an answer will do too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(converting comments to an answer)*

If things like task scheduling, transaction management, consuming data in chunks, flexibility on start/stop operations, retrying mechanisms are things you find yourself spending time into coding yourself then yes definitely take a look at `Spring Batch` it has robust already-implemented facilities of all of the above.

On the grander scheme of things if your application has many moving parts, consuming a lot of external resources you might as well dive into the **EIP** (Enterprise Integration Pattern) waters with `Apache Camel` and `Spring Integration` very solid implementations.

By your description your one-off project(s) are reasonable single-focused so the learning curve of new frameworks might not worth the while. In that case it might suffice to focus on the re-usable components of your projects and externalize them on a core/helper lib for re-usabilitly purposes if that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for summarizing. So in your opinion/experience, Spring-Batch would be a good fit and worth seeing through for this type of situation?

Comment: definately worths a try if you identify any of the above options in your project(s). I would suggest though to first focus on identifying your reusable components before diving into Spring Batch or other frameworks.